# Rails: destroy in wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problems with `destroy` action in my Rails app. 
In my app I have model `UserVotes`, which allows users vote for each other. For example: John votes for other users in the order:

```
Vote for User_1
Vote for User_2
Vote for User_3
```

When John wants to delete his vote for `User_3` he is deleting vote for `User_1`, after retrying he's deleting vote for `User_2`, and only after two attempts he's deleting vote for `User_3`

user_votes_controller:

```
class UserVotesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        @user_vote = UserVote.find_by(params[:recipient_uid])
        @user_vote.destroy
        redirect_to root_url
        flash[:warning] = 'Deleted'
    end

end
```

view:

```
= link_to('Delete vote', user_vote, author_uid: current_user.uid, method: :delete)
```

Comment: post your model definition, your method seems wrong

Comment: there is only `belongs_to :user` in UserVote model

Comment: Why do you need the `UserVote` model? Why not just use the `Vote` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite simple. I just rewrote action `destroy` in users_votes controller:

```
class UserVotesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        @user_vote = UserVote.find(params[:id])
        @user_vote.destroy
        redirect_to root_url
        flash[:warning] = 'Deleted'
    end

end
```

Anyway, thanks for participation!

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of issues in the code you have provided.

1. You seem to be giving recipient_uid in find_by for UserVote, it should be uservote_id.
2. You are finding the vote to destroy by passing the author id, which cant be the unique key in votes. It will just return you the first entry in votes table.

Due to point 2, you are getting the vote to user 1 first, vote to user 2 next and so on. You will have to explain the structure of user,vote,user_vote a little more, if you want me to provide correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_votes
  has_many :votes, :through => :user_votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_votes
  has_many :users, :through => :user_votes
end

class UserVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => :author_uid
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => :recipient_uid
  belongs_to :vote
end
```

The view

```
= link_to('Delete vote', user_vote_path(user_vote), method: :delete)
```

The Controller

```
class UserVotesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        @user_vote = UserVote.find_by(params[:id])
        @vote = @user_vote.vote
        @vote.destroy
        @user_vote.destroy
        redirect_to root_url
        flash[:warning] = 'Deleted'
    end

end
```